# Visibility Binding Not Working

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to toggle the visibility of an Ellipse I have in my UserControl.

PhotoThumbnail.xaml

```
<Ellipse x:Name="EditableEllipse"
             Visibility="{Binding EllipseVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

PhotoThumbnail.xaml.cs

```
private bool _ellipseVisible = false;
    public bool EllipseVisible
    {
        get { return _ellipseVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (_ellipseVisible != value)
            {
                _ellipseVisible = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("EllipseVisible"));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public PhotoThumbnail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
```

and in my Page I want to toggle the visibility based on a Boolean property of if I need to show the Ellipse or not

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
photoThumbnail = new PhotoThumbnail()
{
    EllipseVisible = filter.IsEditable
}
```

I have a BoolVisibilityConverter set up which I know works in other pages. Also, I've declared the converter in App.xaml instead of the UserControl since the `x:Key="BoolVisibilityConverter"` is used throughout the project.

When debugging I place a breakpoint in `PhotoThumbnail.xaml.cs` and confirm that `_ellipseVisible` returns either true or false correctly, but the Visibility of the Ellipse in the UserControl does not update, and always shows visible.

Comment: Are you sure that the DataContext is correctly `PhotoThumbnail` user control? So do you have something in the `PhotoThumbnail.xaml.cs` constructor `DataContext = this;`?

Comment: Above is what exactly is set up. It's weird I just restarted my device and relaunched the solution and it works?